# Design Patterns - Using generic object to update a GUI

Tags: java, swing, oop, design-patterns

My problem is design related. I will first explain what i'm working on and then my current approach which I think should improve but I can't figure out how, hence the question!

So in a nutshell, I parse a raw string to obtain name,value pairs which is then displayed on a GUI. Now this raw string can belong to either `type01` or `type02`. The `type` determines the view I display the name,value pairs on.

`type01` - Contains messy xml, and since I want to preserve the xml hierarchy, my view comprises of a `JXTreeTable`.

`type02` - The name,value data is relatively easy to extract and has a flat structure. Hence my view for this is a `JTable`

I use a `cardlayout` for the two views.

Now let me explain my implementation. Unfortunately i'm not in a position to upload any code, so please bear with me. Anyway this is more of a design issue :)

1. String received. (can be either `type01` or `type02`)
2. Factory class creates appropriate `Parser` object. (`type01Parser` or `type02Parser` both super classed by `Parser`)
3. `Parser` does the parsing and extracts the name,value details to `Object`.
4. `Parser` getter method is used to retrieve the `Object`. which I should be able to use to update my GUI (?)

My problem lies in the `Object` that contains the extracted details. `type01Parser` finally creates a tree structure. Where each node represents a name,value pair. The `Object` is basically the root node. `type02Parser` creates an `ArrayList`, where each element is a name,value pair. The `Object` is the `ArrayList` in this case.

I can hack my way from here, but I really want to follow good design patterns. I believe the return objects should also be super-classed in some way, encapsulating the update functionalities? Also the fact that i'm updating **two completely different UI elements** makes things a bit more confusing. Some general guidance would be highly appreciated.

Although I can't post any code, let me try to explain everything using dummy classes :) Note that i've left out a lot but the general idea is captured. Hopefully

The factory class basically scans the string and determines the type and creates the required parser object

```
...
FactoryParser factory = new FactoryParser(rcvdString);
Parser parser = factory.getBestParser();
Object generalObjectHere = parser.getReturnObject();
...

//whaat next??
```

Abstract Parser class

```
public abstract class Parser{

    Object returnObject=null;
    String str;

    public Parser(String s){
        str=s;
    }

    public void setReturnObject(Object obj){
        returnObject=obj;
    }  

    public Object getReturnObject(){
        return returnObject;
    }  

}
```

Type01Parser

```
public class Type01Parser{

    public Type01Parser(){

        initParser();
        setReturnObject(processAndDoStuff());
    }

    //bunch of methods to process the xml which is in String format.  

}
```

Type02Parser

```
public class Type02Parser{

    public Type02Parser(){

        initParser();
        setReturnObject(processAndDoStuff());
    }

    //bunch of methods to process the string

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your string may contain info about cars or dogs.

You get the best parser, either `CarsParser` or `DogsParser`, both of them extending abstract class Parser.

The returned object should be `Car` or `Dog`, depending on the parser used. Of course, both should extend the same interface (let's say `Response`).

You then pass this object to the view which, depending of type will display contents in the proper view.

Depending on your GUI implementation, the `Response` interface could have a method that returns a `JTable`.